# Контекст this в bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, this, контекст

В связи со следующим кодом

```js
function Popup (pop, name, html, handlers) {
    if (html) {
        $(document.body).append(html);
    }
    handlers = handlers || {};
    this.$pop = $(pop);
    this.selector = pop;
    this.name = name;
    this.$pop_wrapper = this.$pop.parent('.js__popup_main_wrapper');

    Popup.instances[this.name] = this;
    this.$pop.on('click', '.popup__close, .js__popup__close', this.hide.bind(this));

    //Закрытие попапа при клике на маску и при нажатии Esc
    if (this.$pop_wrapper) {
        this.$pop_wrapper.on('click', function(event) {
            var mask_wrapper = event.target;
            if (mask_wrapper.classList.contains('js__popup_main_wrapper')) {
                Popup.hideAll();
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 27) {
            Popup.hideAll();
        }
    });

    this.$body = this.$pop.find('.popup__body_text');

    this.onshow = handlers.show || null;
    this.onhide= handlers.hide || null;

    this.events = {
        closePopup: 'closePopup',
        openPopup: 'openPopup'
    }
}

Popup.instances = {};

Popup.getInstance = function(name, pop, html, handlers) {
    if(Popup.instances[name]){
        return Popup.instances[name];
    }

    if (pop){
        return new Popup(pop, name, html, handlers);
    }
    return null;
};
Popup.hideAll = function() {
    for (var popupName in Popup.instances) {
        if(Popup.instances.hasOwnProperty(popupName)){
            Popup.instances[popupName].hide();
        }
    }
};

Popup.prototype.show = function() {
    Popup.hideAll();

    //Скрываем скролл
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    // временный костыль
    // почему-то не всегда инициализируется dom-элемент попапа
    if (!this.$pop.length) this.$pop = $(this.selector);
    if (!this.$pop.length) return;

    if (this.$pop_wrapper) {
        this.$pop_wrapper.css("display", "flex");
    }

    this.$pop
        .removeClass('hidden')
        .addClass('shown')
        .attr('data-opened', '');
    this.onshow ? this.onshow() : null;

    if (window.userCity && window.userCity.hideBlock) { //если открыт попап города(актуально для мобильной версии)
        //то закрыть блок выбора города
        window.userCity.hideBlock();
    }

    //создадим событие открытия попапа
    eventEmitter.dispatch(this.events.openPopup, {
        popupName: this.name,
        popup: this.$pop
    });
};

Popup.prototype.hide = function() {
    this.$pop
        .removeClass('shown')
        .addClass('hidden')
        .removeAttr('data-opened');
    this.onhide ? this.onhide() : null;

    if (this.$pop_wrapper) {
        this.$pop_wrapper.fadeOut(50);
    }

    var opened = $('[data-opened]').length;

    if (opened === 0) {
        //Возвращаем скролл
        $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
    }

    eventEmitter.dispatch(this.events.closePopup, {
        popupName: this.name,
        popup: this.$pop
    });
};

Popup.prototype.setBodyText = function (text){
    if(!text){
        return;
    }

    this.$body.html(text);
};
```

приведенном на [Семантика свойства this.$pop](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1194442/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-this-pop) был рассмотрен оператор

`this.$pop.on('click', '.popup__close, .js__popup__close', this.hide.bind(this))`.

Возник вопрос:
"Правильно ли я понимаю, что в коде `this.hide.bind(this))`

1. `this` перед `hide` указывает на попап окно,
2. а `this`, который внутри `bind` указывает на иконку закрытия - `'.popup__close, .js__popup__close'`?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.$pop.on('click', '.popup__close, .js__popup__close', this.hide.bind(this));
```

Нет, неправильно. Три `this`-а в этой строчке - это одно и то же.

Comment: а зачем его указывать дважды в таком случае?

Comment: Чтобы при вызове hide, внутри hide был тот же this. Можно добиться того же иначе: `() => this.hide()`

Comment: @ProgrammerOfParadoxThings https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: В `() => this.hide()` только есть нюанс, что его придётся переписывать вслед за методом, если у него изменится количество параметров. А `bind()` делает только привязку this и не трогает аргументы.

Comment: `(...args) => this.hide(...args)` =) Но тут я уже предпочёл бы bind)